# React/Express application only loads on root route, otherwise it loads as JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a React/Express Application, and I'm using React Router.  When I hit the URL http://myapp.com, the React app will load no problem, and I'll have no problem going to other routes.  The issue occurs if I were to instead directly visit any other route, for example http://myapp.com/posts or http://myapp.com/login - there, it will load to the screen the JSON data that the component would have used.  If I were to visit myapp.com and then nagivate to myapp.com/posts and hit the refresh, it will load the JSON data instead.

Any idea how I can get every route to send the static files for every route?

Here is what I have.

The structure I have is as follows:

```
client/
   build/
   node_modules/
   public/
      index.html
   src/
      components/
      redux/
      .gitignore
      index.js
   package.json
models/
node_modules/
public/
routes/
.env
.gitignore
package.json
server.js
```

Server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const postsRouter = require('./routes/posts')
const commentsRouter = require('./routes/comments')
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')
const path = require('path')
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local')
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const User = require('./models/user')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

const app = express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
)

app.use(express.json())

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: herokuUrl,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'],
  })
)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))


app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET))

app.use('/posts', postsRouter)
app.use('/posts/:id/comments', commentsRouter)
app.use('/', usersRouter)

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: 'Invalid search term' })
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If an endpoint is meant to *serve* data (as opposed to serving an actual web page), then you don't use `app.use`, you'd use `app.get` and then have the frontend do an HTTP call to that endpoint. I think you're syncing up frontend and backend routes but that's probably not what you should be doing in your case.

Comment: @Jayce444 `app.use(express.static(...))` is the recommended approach to serving static files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @geenpill could you try moving the `app.use(express.static(...))` calls to below the other routes (i.e. just above the `app.listen`).

We have a similar structure in one of our projects which puts it at the bottom, and the order might matter.

Comment: @TravisValenti yes but I'm assuming these aren't static files, given that it's talking about posts and comments like a social media site type thing, i's likely dynamic data fetched from a DB - could use clarification

Comment: Yes, Jayce.  My express routes will query a DB and send it to the client as JSON.

Comment: @TravisValenti I tried moving them below the express routes and nothing changed.  :(  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for updating the question with more information.

It seems your issue is that you have react routes at `/posts`, `/login`, etc. and also API routes at the same locations.

When `react-router-dom` goes to a new location, it doesn't make another request to your server as it already has all the files it needs (i.e. your index.js, css files, etc.), but when you refresh the page your browser is making a GET request to that location (e.g. `/posts`).

Your express server is seeing the request and responding with JSON.

What you will need to do is make sure that you don't have GET request handlers with the same path as you have routes.

My recommendation (though there are plenty of other ways) is to put your API handlers at `/api`. For example, `/api/posts`. Then, when you go to the url at `/posts` it will load from the static files, but when you make a GET request to `/api/posts` express will know to serve the JSON.